# How to make table scrollable in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making one div and onclick of div I am making some table. I am getting the table value. I want my table to be scrollable.

Here is my code.

```
var myTable = '<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" title="Type in a name">'+
            '<table id="myTable">'+ '<tr class="header"></tr>' + '<tr><td></td></tr>'+ '</table>';
```

I am getting this table data from some proxy. I want size of table should be limited and if data is more this shoud be scrollable.

CSS which I am applying here is

```
#myInput {
  background-image: url('Drop.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 30%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

Any way to proceed this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple, with fixed `max-height`, set `overflow: auto`, if table higher than 150px, a scrollbar will present.

```
thead,
tbody {
  display: block;
}

tbody {
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```css
thead,
tbody {
  display: block;
}

tbody {
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('Drop.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 30%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" title="Type in a name">
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @David glad to help

Answer (score 3):

```
#myTable
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Or Table with fixed header

```
tbody {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

This might not work with IE some versions. If you want to work all browsers, You can get into the `div` your table and set its `height` and `overflow` attributes.Like following;

```
var myTable = '<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" title="Type in a name">'+
        '<div class="scrollable"><table id="myTable">'+ '<tr class="header"></tr>' + '<tr><td></td></tr>'+ '</table></div>';
```

and css

```
.scrollable
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

There are a lot of solution to this. You can also define nested tables or if you want,you can apply scroll only rows, and etc...

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)